# Getting value of an input box within an HREF element using Javascript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button in a JSP which, when pressed, makes a GET request to a servlet.
The following is the link, and it works fine, calling the servlet and correctly passing the `id` parameter.

```
<a id="sButton" href="javascript:perform('editShow(/auth/mkt/mgmt/save?id=1)');">
</a>
```

I need to add another parameter to the GET request. This will be the value entered by the user in an input box, which has an id of `newPrefix`. I understand that the following JQuery will retrieve the value:

```
$('#newPrefix').val()
```

The question is, how to incorporate the above into the HREF.

I have tried the following

```
<a id="sButton" href="javascript:perform('editShow(/auth/mkt/mgmt/save?newPrefix=$('#newPrefix').val()&amp;id=1)');">
</a>
```

But this fails. The servlet method is called, but the parameters are not passed correctly.

`newPrefix` is received as `$('`

`id` is received as `null`

What is the correct way to get the value of the input box within the HREF ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anchor with `href=javascript:` executes javascript function, in your case,

```js
perform('editShow(/auth/mkt/mgmt/save?id=1)');
```

That means that you will invoke `perform` with `editShow(/auth/mkt/mgmt/save?id=1)` as **String**.

After we understood that, all you need to do is to concat an additional value.

```js
'editShow(/auth/mkt/mgmt/save?id=1&amp;newPrefix=' + $('#newPrefix').val() + ')'
```

Final code:

```html
<a id="sButton" href="javascript:perform('editShow(/auth/mkt/mgmt/save?id=1&amp;newPrefix=' + $('#newPrefix').val() + ')');">
</a>
```